# rank partition by not returning as intented

Tags: mysql

I have this code here `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT eventi_curseason.nome_evento, campionato_id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY eventi_curseason.team_home_name, campionato_id ORDER BY eventi_curseason.data_evento DESC) AS rnk, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY eventi_curseason.team_away_name, campionato_id ORDER BY eventi_curseason.data_evento DESC) AS rnk2 FROM eventi_curseason where eventi_curseason.status_short = 'FT' ) AS x where rnk <= 5 and rnk2 <=5`
which is supposed to return top 5 of each category, only problem is that sometimes it returns only 4 instead of 5, if I remove the "where" clause it returns more than 4, so I guess it must bet that clause.

[image: mySQL table]

This is what I mean, in this case "Cagliari" is returned 5 times, but torino only 4 even if checking manually Torino should pop up.

Note: I wrote "Torino" in the search bar to only show up Torino because I know that one is bugged. Torino U19 and Torino are not the same of course

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question, but you might want to group your results by `rnk`.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The problem is that in this case, Torino rnk only returns 4 times instead of 5. If I don't put the "where" clause it returns more than 20 for rnk and rnk2, so <= than 5 should return 5 instead of 4